no option in visual studio to enter password to connect to host
We have connected our host website in visual studio to work on project.
we changed password through hostinger dashboard. now when we tried to connect to that host, we are getting an error as below . also we are not seeing any option to enter new password to connect to host. we are not using .ppk file but we are using password.


Perhaps this will be helpful? How to confirm a new remote host key in Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH extension?

but we are not using ssh, we are using password. it connects well in filezilla but not in visual studio
